# Can't access Linux machine from the network, network from the machine is fine

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10

I'm having issues with a machine that stopped replicating with mysql. 
It's managed by a guy on another continent but recently I've had to get involved.

The server is running Ubuntu server 9.10

I can't log in with SSH, there is no response.  On the server itself I can ssh to localhost fine.

I thought maybe it's the firewall rules.  I'm no expert on IP Tables, but I believe that's not the issue as I removed all the rules.  But it still won't let me in.

Any ideas?  it's acting from other machines as though the service isn't listening, but I know that it is.  It's like this for all services.

Comment: Are these on the same subnet?  If not, run a tracepath from each side to the other and post results, may help.

Comment: No the server I was accessing with and the server are in different networks.  Turns out the other guy changed the default gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the default gateway set correctly on the server?

Comment: Turns out this was the problem.  What I didn't count on was another person changing the default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Try ssh on the local box to it's LAN IP as localhost most likely was 127.0.0.1.

Just in case sshd is configured to only listen on 127.0.0.1 for some reason.

You can check /etc/ssh/sshd_config for the ListenAddress setting to confirm.  It should either be commented out, 0.0.0.0 or the actual IP you want it to listen on.

Comment: It was commented out.  Changed it to 0.0.0.0... discovered that I can now access it from just one machine on the network, I think my firewall is now getting in the way but astaro isn't showing anything in it's logs.

Answer (score 0):

You should run through the standard networking debugging steps 
1. Do I have an ip address (ifconfig) 
2. Can I ping my Gateway (ping x.x.x.x where x.x.x.x is the gateway) 
3. is my service running and listening on a port accessable to the world(netstat -lnp | grep ssh ) 
4. is my firewall blocking this port (iptables -L)